# Django - querying multiple values using foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I am new to Django and trying to understand the model relationships. I have two models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.Charfield(max_length = 15)
    
class Books(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    authors = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

In my views.py I am accessing the records like this:

```
class BooksViewSet(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        data = Books.objects.all()
```

Now suppose I have multiple books with multiple authors, how do I create an API which would include all the authors of the books? I think I need to filter out the values but am not exactly sure how it is done. Currently, I get only one author using the above views.py. Sorry if I missed the obvious. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Instead of a `ForeignKey` you want to be using a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)

Comment: The above is correct. If for some reason you don't want to change the design of the tables, consider `prefetch_related` as eg Books.objects.all().prefetch_related('authors')